# What unit is Zoom in OpenLayer3?

Tags: openlayers

I need to know the type of unit that Zoom, or maxZoom/minZoom has. 
I've been finding in OpenLayers API but without success.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**
The zoom of `ol.View` is not in any unit, it is just an incrementing integer id for a given resolution.

**Longer answer:**

Zooming in OpenLayers 3 is entirely based on resolution. The resolution is the number of map units per pixel and can vary continuously between the `minResolution` and `maxResolution`. The resolution is however *constrained* to a set of resolutions, which the map will snap to after zoom interactions.

The zoom index/number is nothing more than an enumeration of these resolutions, where `0` is the highest resolution, `1` is the second and so on. So when you do `view.setZoom(6)`, all you're doing is setting the resolution to the seventh constraint resolution.

So what are those resolutions? It all depends on your configuration:

- If using the `resolution` option, it's value is the constraint resolutions
- Otherwise, the resolutions will be calculated from the `maxResolution` and `zoomFactor`:

  - The `zoomFactor` defaults to `2`, but is configurable
  - The `maxResolution` is calculated as the resolution for fitting the projection's extent in 256*256 pixels, if not explicitly provided
  - The resolution for a given zoom level when calculated this way will be `maxResolution / Math.pow(zoomFactor, zoomLevel)`
  - The `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options will limit which of these resolutions that will be usable. `maxZoom` will determine how many such resolutions are calculated, if `maxZoom` is 20 then there will be 21 resolutions. But if `minZoom` is more than 0 the first `minZoom` of those resolutions will be ignored.